# Why aren't dictionaries callable?

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, call

It's a usual programming problem to have a list of objects that you want to map into another. This is usually done with a dictionary:

```
l1=[1,2,3]
d={1:'_ONE', 2:'_TWO', 3:'_THREE'}
l2= [d[i] for i in l1]
```

In many cases, it's natural to see a dictionary as a function that maps keys to values. Then, you'd simply `l2= map(d,l1)` instead of using the list comprehension (or the ugly `map(d.__getitem__,l1)`.

Of course, since python is so flexible, you can get this behaviour easily:

```
class CallableDict(dict):
    def __call__(self, k):
        return self[k]
```

but this obviously doesn't work when accessing dicts you don't create yourself.

Are there good reasons why the base python dictionaries are not callable by default?

*Disclaimer: The motivation for this question is mostly ruby, where dictionaries work this way*

Comment: Because calling is something entirely different from indexing? In Python, there is also **one obvious way to do something**, adding call support would add a second way to do something.

Comment: Also, `i` might not be in `d`: `map(d.get, l)` would be better, as it prevents `KeyError` (of course, you might not want that).

Comment: @MartijnPieters The "one obvious way to do it" is probably the strongest reason. I'd argue that the notion of "indexing" is hardly appropriate to dictionaries (a dictionary defines "index" as "a **sequential** arrangement of material, especially in alphabetical or numerical order"), but of course, that is how the majority of programming languages do it

Comment: @goncalopp: the official term is [subscription](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions); calling is fundamentally different from subscriptions and the two actions are distinct.

Comment: You are somewhat correct, as in many instances, item-getting or attribute-getting are handled by function calls, so for those cases the "subscription" boundaries are blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it. http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

If you make `dict` callable to subscript a dictionary, now you have two ways of doing the same thing:

```
d[k]  # Existing
d(k)  # Proposed
```

Even the case that you bring up, having a callable to pass to `map`, already has one obvious solution:

```
map(d.get, it)  # Existing
map(d, it)      # Proposed
```

There doesn't seem to be any particular advantage to your proposal, and it duplicates what are already obvious ways.

Comment: Shamelessly stolen from  Martijn Pieters and  jonrsharpe. This answer is a community wiki, feel free to edit and improve.